# "Future Post" is appearing next to blog posts

Tags: nodes

How to disable the words "Future post" appearing in Italics next to blog titles? Blog posts scheduled for future time are showing up "Future post" text....I am having a hard time figuring how to get rid of this text. Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

[image: Future Post]

Comment: Is there code adding this text? Css? A module? What drives this? Is this Drupal 7 or 8?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the source code of course, but based on the text differences I'm assuming you could CSS to change the display or visibility of that particular text, or if that's not an option as it hides needed text in blog posts elsewhere, you could make a custom template file for that content type and adjust it accordingly from there.